# ¿Cómo logro que python me detecte un archivo csv?

Tags: python

Quiero que python me detecte un archivo csv para luego trabajar con el, así es como lo estoy haciendo

```
files_name = os.listdir('C: \database/db.csv')
for file in files_name:

    f = open ('database/db.csv/'+file)
    content = csv.load(f)
    print(content)
    print()
```

Al momento de ejecutar, me dice que no encuentra la ruta especificada, sin embargo, cuanto leo el archivo normal, con .reader si me lo muestra. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?
Gracias

Comment: Tu archivo py esta en el directorio c:?

Answer (score 0):

Para leer un archivo .csv necesitas usar alguno de los lectores de la librería `csv`.

#### Método simple

El método más simple permite leer cada línea del csv transformada en una lista de valores.

```
files_name = os.listdir('/home/candid/PycharmProjects/pandas2')
for file in files_name:
    if file.lower().endswith(".csv"):
        print(f"Archivo {file}")
        f = open (file)
        csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
        for x in csv_reader:
            print(x)
```

Primero obtenemos la lista de archivos, de los cuales sólo nos interesan los que terminan en `.csv`. Primero tenemos que abrir el archivo (`open`) y luego crear un lector de .csv con él usando `csv.reader(f)`.

`csv.reader` es el lector más básico. Toma cada línea del archivo de entrada, lo separa según su delimitador ("," por default) y lo retorna en una lista.

Este código produce:

```
Archivo titanic.csv
['PassengerId', 'Survived', 'Pclass', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Ticket', 'Fare', 'Cabin', 'Embarked']
['1', '0', '3', 'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris', 'male', '22', '1', '0', 'A/5 21171', '7.25', '', 'S']
['2', '1', '1', 'Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)', 'female', '38', '1', '0', 'PC 17599', '71.2833', 'C85', 'C']
['3', '1', '3', 'Heikkinen, Miss. Laina', 'female', '26', '0', '0', 'STON/O2. 3101282', '7.925', '', 'S']
['4', '1', '1', 'Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)', 'female', '35', '1', '0', '113803', '53.1', 'C123', 'S']
... y un montón de registros más.
```

Nota que la primera línea es el encabezado del .csv (nombres de columnas), pero aquí se lee y se trata igual que el resto.

#### Método con diccionario

El método `csv.DictReader()` es un lector que retorna cada línea en un diccionario. Esto es mucho más cómodo, pues podemos recuperar los campos por su nombre.

```
for file in files_name:
    if file.lower().endswith(".csv"):
        print(f"Archivo {file}")
        f = open (file)
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        for x in csv_reader:
            print(x)
```

El nombre de la llave se saca del encabezado. Por tanto, el .csv tiene que traer el encabezado.

produce:

```
Archivo titanic.csv
{'PassengerId': '1', 'Survived': '0', 'Pclass': '3', 'Name': 'Braund, Mr. Owen Harris', 'Sex': 'male', 'Age': '22', 'SibSp': '1', 'Parch': '0', 'Ticket': 'A/5 21171', 'Fare': '7.25', 'Cabin': '', 'Embarked': 'S'}
{'PassengerId': '2', 'Survived': '1', 'Pclass': '1', 'Name': 'Cumings, Mrs. John Bradley (Florence Briggs Thayer)', 'Sex': 'female', 'Age': '38', 'SibSp': '1', 'Parch': '0', 'Ticket': 'PC 17599', 'Fare': '71.2833', 'Cabin': 'C85', 'Embarked': 'C'}
{'PassengerId': '3', 'Survived': '1', 'Pclass': '3', 'Name': 'Heikkinen, Miss. Laina', 'Sex': 'female', 'Age': '26', 'SibSp': '0', 'Parch': '0', 'Ticket': 'STON/O2. 3101282', 'Fare': '7.925', 'Cabin': '', 'Embarked': 'S'}
{'PassengerId': '4', 'Survived': '1', 'Pclass': '1', 'Name': 'Futrelle, Mrs. Jacques Heath (Lily May Peel)', 'Sex': 'female', 'Age': '35', 'SibSp': '1', 'Parch': '0', 'Ticket': '113803', 'Fare': '53.1', 'Cabin': 'C123', 'Embarked': 'S'}
{'PassengerId': '5', 'Survived': '0', 'Pclass': '3', 'Name': 'Allen, Mr. William Henry', 'Sex': 'male', 'Age': '35', 'SibSp': '0', 'Parch': '0', 'Ticket': '373450', 'Fare': '8.05', 'Cabin': '', 'Embarked': 'S'}
{'PassengerId': '6', 'Survived': '0', 'Pclass': '3', 'Name': 'Moran, Mr. James', 'Sex': 'male', 'Age': '', 'SibSp': '0', 'Parch': '0', 'Ticket': '330877', 'Fare': '8.4583', 'Cabin': '', 'Embarked': 'Q'}
{'PassengerId': '7', 'Survived': '0', 'Pclass': '1', 'Name': 'McCarthy, Mr. Timothy J', 'Sex': 'male', 'Age': '54', 'SibSp': '0', 'Parch': '0', 'Ticket': '17463', 'Fare': '51.8625', 'Cabin': 'E46', 'Embarked': 'S'}
{'PassengerId': '8', 'Survived': '0', 'Pclass': '3', 'Name': 'Palsson, Master. Gosta Leonard', 'Sex': 'male', 'Age': '2', 'SibSp': '3', 'Parch': '1', 'Ticket': '349909', 'Fare': '21.075', 'Cabin': '', 'Embarked': 'S'}
{'PassengerId': '9', 'Survived': '1', 'Pclass': '3', 'Name': 'Johnson, Mrs. Oscar W (Elisabeth Vilhelmina Berg)', 'Sex': 'female', 'Age': '27', 'SibSp': '0', 'Parch': '2', 'Ticket': '347742', 'Fare': '11.1333', 'Cabin': '', 'Embarked': 'S'}
```